# Combine rank-2 Numpy arrays of different dimensions with custom function using vectorised operations

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a custom function that takes two one-dimensional Numpy arrays of the same size (length=D) and returns a number.

```
import numpy as np
def myfunc(v1, v2):
    assert type(v1) is np.ndarray
    assert type(v2) is np.ndarray
    assert len(v1) == len(v2)

    # example calculation
    calculated_number = np.abs(v1.mean() - v2.mean())

    return calculated_number
```

I also have two arrays with the following dimensions:

```
A1.shape = (m,D)
A2.shape = (n,D)
```

I want to combine A1 and A2 in a sort of external product that would generate an array of shape (m,n), but instead of multiplication use the custom function, as such:

```
A_out = np.zeros((m,n))
for i in range(m):
    v1 = A1[i]

    for j in range(n):
        v2 = A2[j]

        A_out[i,j] = myfunc(v1,v2)
```

From [*Python for Data Analysis* by Wes McKinney](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html#I_indexterm4_id284397):

> Arrays are important because they enable you to express batch operations on data without writing any `for` loops. This is usually called *vectorization*.

**Question**: How can I express the above in a **vectorised form**; i.e., using purely Numpy array operations instead of `for` loops and native Python operations?

N.B.: The question is specifically on vectorisation, so I'm looking for a solution that would work for any appropriate function.

Comment: You may not be able to do it for an arbitrary function. The crux here is actually `# [function calculations here]`

Comment: That being said, if `# [function calculations here]` is properly vectorizable, you can probably vectorize the entire thing.

Comment: You start by learning the basics of numpy, those **purely numpy operations**. The 'vectorization' the book takes about uses numpy building blocks.

Comment: @hpaulj, that's what I'm doing: I've tried different things, but I can only get this to work for D = 1, hence the question here. "Go study the relevant material" is not a helpful answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, would be able to provide an answer for this if you assumed the function was "properly vectorizable" (what's the precise definition?), or would you still need to know the exact function?

Comment: @Ratler. I would need to know the definition

Comment: I've added an example definition, but since the question asks for a general way, I guess the answer should start by saying that it's not possible if that is, indeed, the case.

Comment: If you can write your operations as `A[i, j] = f(v1[i], v2[j])` where `f` consists of basic operations and is uniform for all `(i, j)`, then most likely it will be vectorizable.

Comment: @swag2198, to clarify, it would be `A[i, j] = f(v1, v2)`, not `v1[i] and v2[j]`. See updated example function in question.